# Does Pascal automatically "trim" arrays that are function input parameters?

Tags: arrays, function, parameters, pascal

I am working on a Pascal-to-C port and the way the two languages differ in handling strings has become a frustrating issue.

If I declare a Pascal character array `A` of size `x` and pass it as an input argument to a function with an input parameter defined as a character array B of size x-z, where z is a positive integer, what does Pascal do once it is inside the function? Is the array A truncated and B treated inside the function as though it is of size x-z?

The way that the original source is written seems to indicate that this is how it works, but I am unfamiliar with Pascal.

I cannot post the code as it is proprietary, nor do I know much about Pascal syntax. However, it would be something along the lines of:

```
type1 string[22]
type2 string[10]

//Function definition
function(type2 in)
    //Do stuff to the array
    print(in)

//Function call
type2 temp = "This is a string of 20"
function(inputString)
```

There may be syntax errors

```
(* Types *)
type24 = packed array[1..24] of char;
type40 = packed array[1..40] of char;

(* Variable declaration *)
line : type40;

(* Function prototype *)
foo(var contents : type24) : boolean;

(* Function call *)
if ( foo(line) )
begin
end
```

Comment: Please post some code that explains what you're asking (it should be just a few lines). I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. Pascal does not ever "trim" arrays, but without code it's hard to say what it actually does; I can't tell what you're seeing from the description.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include a pseudo code example. my question is what doe the string "in" look like inside the procedure?

Comment: Please do not take this disrespectfully, but that is why it is called "pseudo" code. I have added illustrative code to the best of my abilities. I do not claim to know PASCAL, I only work in C most of the time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your "pseudo code" isn't actual Pascal (it wouldn't compile, both because the function declaration is wrong and because the compiler wouldn't let you assign a string of more than 10 characters to a variable of `type2`). Please post actual **compilable** code that illustrates what you're asking. What you posted now as code is nonsense - it won't compile, and you create a variable  named `temp` but call the `function` (which, btw, can't be named `function` either) with `inputstring`.

Comment: But it can't illustrate the issue you're trying to solve, either, because it isn't actual pseudo-code. You're asking a specific syntax type question, without posting the syntax you're asking about - how do you expect to get an answer other than "No, Pascal does not trim arrays."?

Comment: Your two examples will behave differently. In the first one the string will be truncated at compile time, but it will of type2. The second example won't compile, compiler won't allow to pass a type40 in place of a type24. Might depend on compiler though.

Comment: If you're "working on a Pascal to C port" and you're having issues that led you to ask this question, you should have some representative code that you could quickly anonymize and post that would illustrate the problem. Why aren't you posting it?

Comment: Thank you Sertac. In the second example the types are exactly as used in the original source. The original authors must have set the compiler to ignore the errors. Ken, the second was meant to provide a scrubbed version. Pretend that function is not a keyword. I will edit it in the question. And yes, and answer of "no" is acceptable. How is it syntax? I declare two types, one larger than the other, and pass in a variable declared under the larger type to a function defined with the smaller type as the type of the input argument. (this is a serious question not a smart a** remark)

Comment: I believe that the answer I was looking for was that PASCAL is pass by reference as C is when dealing with strings. In order for the second example function call to work as intended in C, the larger string input must be cast as a smaller string type pointer. In PASCAL you may not have to explicitly cast the variable to a pointer type that matches the function definition input type in order to achieve the same result.

Comment: If the declaration was in the parameter declaration it could have been a so called "Conformant Array". A kind of open array in more ISO oriented Pascals that has both a lower and upper bound. If so, the bounds of the array are hiddenly passed to the function, and the compiler will do proper bound checking and index adjustment to match the passed arrays declaration with the parameter declaration used inside the function. It will make it easier if you specify the Pascal dialect, since it rules out archaic dialects.

Comment: It is a proprietary version of PASCAL developed by Honeywell.